# Invalid Conversion Specifier - SQLite - xCode Objective C

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite, compiler-construction

I have just updated my compiler after downloading the new version of xCode. I am getting the following error around this piece of SQLite code :

```
if (pack !=YES) {

        query = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"SELECT Name, Description, Postcode, AddressLine1, ImageURL, Free, Area, OpeningTimes, NearestTube, Cost,UniqueID, URL, Number, FirstLetter, FirstLetterArea FROM MainDetails WHERE Free='Y' AND FirstLetterArea = '%@%' ORDER BY Area",tmpLike];

    }
```

The error is "Invalid conversion specifier 'O'". The error underlines the letter 'O' in the ORDER BY statement.

This makes no sense to me - is this a glitch in the compiler or is there a valid reason ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the second percent character in `'%@%'`.